# Excel Vlookup Missing data unless re-typed or select and enter?

Tags: vba, excel

Google has not found the solution i need so i thought i would try the genius on here to the never ending Excel issue I'm having.

Running a banking reconciliation workbook and slowly adding bits of VBA together to automate some of the tasks, one I'm working on now is finding large quantities of money and renaming their Identifier from a bank statement to same ID in our cashbook to they are found and will balance out.

To do this I'm running a IF(Vlookup()) returning a yes or no on the cash value and then reordering them once they are found so i can line them up and match them correctly.

The main issue I've got here is the vlookup is ignoring some values which i can see and saying no not found and i messed around figuring out why and until i clicked to edit the cell and then pressed enter not changing the amount and all of a sudden found and it only finds it in the vlookup if i click the cell and press enter.

I have tried Formatting, changing calculation to automate and tweaked the vlookup to include a +0 as well as changing the exact match to approximate and it still won't find it, i even tried trimming and checked the Len for whitespace and both equal the same.

Currently trying a for loop  to select a cell and change it to itself so it mimics the select and enter but it runs slow and crashes.

Anyone got a decent idea of fixing this miss when searching

Comment: Can you post a sample spreadsheet (with sensitive data removed) example that demonstrates the problem, on some publically accessible file sharing site (e.g. dropbox, onedrive, etc), and post a link in your question?

Comment: finished work so i won't be able to upload one until tomorrow when I'm back.

Answer (score 1):

This often happens to me when pasting data from somewhere. It may have been pasted as text but then when you edit and press enter it changes to numeric.

The solution is to use `=VALUE()` to change the numbers to numeric.

Or when you paste the data from another source choose paste special as text.

Comment: + 1 `paste special as text`.. I agree with that. A quick suggestion though. Formatting the column as number before pasting may help.

Comment: Using Data ► Text to Columns ► Fixed Width ► Finish is a quick way to convert an entire column of pseudo-numbers to actual numbers providing the column is formatted as *General* or one of the number format masks.

Comment: Adding 0 or multiplying by 1 is another way to quickly convert numbers stored as text to numbers.

Comment: i tried the value() and it didn't make a difference, i also tried formatting the cells prior to the copy and it still ignores it and the copy and paste data code does do it as a paste special as text so that won't work either

Comment: @Jimjebus There are many possible problems with your IF statement or with your VLOOKUP. Without knowing more it is difficult to say.

Answer (score 0):

`VLOOKUP` works strangely when is asked to do an approximate match with the look-up table unsorted by the look-up column.

If you're sure that an exact match should be enforced in your look-up column, try something along the lines of:

```
VLOOKUP(<lookup_value>, <table_array>, <col_index_num>, FALSE)
```

where `<lookup_value>`, `<table_array>`, `<col_index_num>` should be replaced with the values that you use in your look-up.

Comment: Its its already set up like this, an example for 1 cell is =IF(ISNA(VLOOKUP(J6,C6:C36,1,FALSE)),"No","Yes") which works well but its still missing values , e.g. J23 is 21,654.61 which is also present in my range but it wont find it depsite its being in there unless i click to edit it and press enter